# iPhone CAAnimations playing serially

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to define all CAAnimations at start and play them one after another serially without using delegates, like what we do in CAAnimationGroup, where in animations are played simultaneously. Instead I just want them to play serially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a set of `CAAnimation` animations in sequence, group them in a `CAAnimationGroup` and set the `beginTime` and `duration` of each `CAAnimation` so that they are run one after the other.

Most people miss these properties because they're defined in the `CAMediaTiming`, which `CAAnimation` conforms to.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me a millions, one question though what does removeOnCompletion is used for, i mean i never noticed any difference by setting it to "FALSE"?

Comment: The properties of an animation layer for a view are distinct from the properties of the view itself. For instance, if you animate the position of a view via a CALayer, unless you also set the actual position of the view it will snap back to its' original position if removedOnCompletion is set to YES.